# Book representation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have a book that can contain hundreds, maybe thousands, of pages and I need to highlight every single word or phrase, that user searches for. For example: user enters a word/phrase that he wants to find and starts listing through the book from first to last page, pages are being lazy loaded. When there is word/phrase he entered, its highlighted.

I couldn't find a way how to store text of the book:

- When I store it in a single field, its extremely long and I need to load it by pages. However I haven't found any way of returning only part, which represents one page, of text field with highlighted words.
- When I split the text into pages and store them as nested objects or stand-alone documents, its impossible to highlight phrases that span across several pages. I need to merge all the pages together, highlight it and then return it page by page, but I haven't found a way how it can be done.

What is the best way to store book in Elasticsearch when I want to search through it and also display it page by page?

Comment: Have you considered storing the text in chunks (pages probably work best here) that may have some redundant overlap, but allow you to get the behavior you're looking for?

This approach would obviously be less storage efficient, but it may be a relatively easy way to accomplish your goal. Essentially: Store a document as the entirety of page 1, store another document as the second half of page 1 and the first half of page 2 (indexing it as being pages 1-2 or 1 and 2, depending on how you want to structure it), making sure your chunk size is dependent an upper limit for search length

Comment: You could run a more robust server option like Apache Lucene or Solr - have you looked at either? https://lucene.apache.org. What you seem to be describing is what these servers are made for.

Comment: Maybe a little bit of string processing might enable you to merge highlight segments across pages. Is that possible for you?

Comment: @MikeMichaels yes, I was thinking about that, but the problem is that the search lenght is not limited, in other words, in some cases the search phrase can span across several (not only two) pages.

Comment: @JonathanBowman I will definitely take a look at that

Comment: @ArchitSaxena I really have no idea what do you mean. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Marmellad Is limiting to even a large size off the table (4+ pages?). If you can restrict it to any degree, then you can chunk accordingly

Comment: @Marmellad, sorry i've been away. I was building upon storing individual pages as documents and for merging highlight segments across consecutive pages, you could process the results in the application.